# Pandas ignoring headers while reading large (2GB) csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to read a rather large CSV (2 GB) with pandas to do some datatype manipulation and joining with other dataframes I have already loaded before. As I want to be a little careful with memory I decided to read the it in chunks. For the purpose of the questions here is an extract of my CSV layout with dummy data (cant really share the real data, sorry!):

```
institution_id,person_id,first_name,last_name,confidence,institution_name
1141414141,4141414141,JOHN,SMITH,0.7,TEMP PLACE TOWN
10123131114,4141414141,JOHN,SMITH,0.7,TEMP PLACE CITY
1003131313188,4141414141,JOHN,SMITH,0.7,"TEMP PLACE,TOWN"
18613131314,1473131313,JOHN,SMITH,0.7,OTHER TEMP PLACE
192213131313152,1234242383,JANE,SMITH,0.7,"OTHER TEMP INC, LLC"
```

My pandas code to read the files:

```
inst_map = pd.read_csv("data/hugefile.csv",
                       engine="python",
                       chunksize=1000000,
                       index_col=False)

print("processing institution chunks")

chunk_list = []  # append each chunk df here
for chunk in inst_map:
    # perform data filtering
    chunk['person_id'] = chunk['person_id'].progress_apply(zip_check)
    chunk['institution_id'] = chunk['institution_id'].progress_apply(zip_check)

    # Once the data filtering is done, append the chunk to list
    chunk_list.append(chunk)

ins_processed = pd.concat(chunk_list)
```

The `zip check` function that I'm applying is basically performing some datatype checks and then converting the value that it gets into an integer.

Whenever I read the CSV it will only ever read the `institution_id` column and generates an index. The other columns in the CSV are just silently dropped.

When i dont use index_col=False as an option it will just set `1141414141/4141414141/JOHN/SMITH/0.7` (basically the first 5 values in the row) as the index and only `institution_id` as the header while only reading the `institution_name` into the dataframe as a value.

I have honestly no clue what is going on here, and after 2 hours of SO / google search I decided to just ask this as a question. Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I seem to have a similar problem. When I just copy a subset of the data into a new file the problem does not come up which lets me to believe its a formatting issue of the csv. Do you happen to know what formatting error can cause pandas to read a csv in the way i described above?

Comment: Try setting the chunk size smaller, to perhaps 10.  Also add an enumerator to your for loop and stop if after a few loops. Then see if you get the same issue.  If not keep increasing the stop point until you reproduce your error.  This will at least narrow down where in your file the issue is.

Comment: It seems like that even when I only use a chunk size of 10 the whole dataframe breaks like described. I suspect something must be wrong with the CSV file itself. It's just weird that whatever other tool I use (CSViewer) it just works. Only pandas is giving me issues. I think I will have to investigate a litte bit more into the file itself.

Comment: Update: Thanks @James ! The issue came out to be that something went wrong while transferring the large CSV file to my remote processing server (which sufficient RAM to handle in memory editing). Processing the chunks on my local computer seems to work. I think i will have to reupload the larger files or try a different processing approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came out to be that something went wrong while transferring the large CSV file to my remote processing server (which sufficient RAM to handle in memory editing). Processing the chunks on my local computer seems to work.

After reuploading the file it worked fine on the remote server.